# ShowDialog without Blocking Caller

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a strong named assembly.

This has been asked before...but only sort of and with a different purpose.

I have a Form base class. When the implementing class sets a property on the base class `IsBusy`. I want to block all interaction with the Form (setting Enabled = false is not enough - I also want to block moving, resizing, closing, etc....and I don't want my controls to look disabled when `IsBusy == true`) and show a popup loading form in front (a transparent, borderless form with a loading animation).

Calling ShowDialog on my loading animation form does the trick in terms of blocking interaction on the calling form...but obviously I also want the calling forms code to continue executing.

Right now I'm using new LoadingForm().Show(), then handling WndProc on my calling Form and if `IsBusy == true` I supress all WndProc messages...but I don't like this approach. It prevents the form from repainting too, which I don't want.

I wouldn't mind the WndProc approach so much if I knew all the different types of messages to let through to allow correct repainting while `IsBusy == true`...but I don't.

So, my question is:

Is there a better solution?

or

Cans someone tell what WndProc messages I should let through? Or where to find a glossary?

Thanks.

Comment: "obviously I also want the calling forms thread to continue executing" - just don't do anything and it will. Looks like you're solving a problem that isn't there.

Comment: One way to do this is to start a new Thread to run the operation (not the original UI thread) and have the completion of that Thread close the 'busy' dialog (via Invoke) so that the message pump reverts control to the original form.  One standard encapsulation of this is using BackgroundWorker.

Comment: You're right, using a BackgroundWorder would eliminate the problem. But I want to make this change centrally...and I know that some places don't use a BackgroundWorker, which would leave those places non functional after this change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up BeginInvoke'ing a ShowDialog:

```
myForm.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => new LoadingForm().ShowDialog()));
```

that has the desired effect of letting code after that line continue to run and still blocking all interaction with myForm.

Comment: I don't think so. No one gave this as a potential solution. Not even close.

Comment: how do you then close the form? myForm.EndInvoke({what is put here});

Comment: Yeah, would be nice to know!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to let through painting, allow `WM_PAINT` and `WM_NCPAINT`.

Comment: Is there a static class with all named message values or something? Or is there a good glossary with int values provided?

Comment: pinvoke.net can meet all your pinvoking needs: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html

Answer (score 2):

You are making it too complicated.  All you have to do is prevent the dialog from getting closed.  Implement the FormClosing event (or override OnFormClosing, better) and set e.Cancel = true while the operation is busy.  There's then nothing the user can do to disturb your process.

This is all assuming that you used a worker thread to implement the operation.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the problem correctly. I don't want to rely on every inheriting Form to only be able to safely set IsBusy = true from a background thread. It's not just closing I want to prevent, it's all interaction.

Comment: You'll have to give an example of an interaction that's possible in this case.  There's none that I can think of.

Comment: Ok, so the only way the Loading Window acts as a Dialog is if I call ShowDialog on it, right? If I do that, it blocks the calling thread. So, the guy who sets myForm.IsBusy = true will hang at that line and never have a chance to set IsBusy back to false....so the Loading Form will stay up forever. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Setting it back to false in a BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted event handler for example is not a problem.

Comment: You're right. I'm saying it's blocking the Thread...but what's it's really doing is starting a new message loop. Either way, it has the same effect. Calling new Form().ShowDialog() will 1) block at the calling line and start a new Message Loop. 2) Prevent interaction will the from behind the new form. Point 1 is what I need to avoid.

Comment: Yes.  It otherwise doesn't prevent code running, including events dispatched through the nested message loop.

Comment: Right, but I don't want to prevent the subsequent code from running after the caller sets IsBusy = true. In this scenario, if I have two lines in Form_Load: IsBusy = true; IsBusy = false;, the screen will hang forever.

Comment: You're right, using a BackgroundWorder would eliminate the problem. But I want to make this change centrally...and I know that some places don't use a BackgroundWorker, which would leave those places non functional after this change.

Comment: Hmm, you missed the last line in my post.  If you continue running code then the user interface goes catatonic.  Your WndProc() won't run anymore, nothing will repaint either.  Everything is dead as a doornail until that code returns.  There's then no point in doing anything special, the UI won't respond anyway.